# Is there any library on python MSN

Tags: python, msn

As title, I am in a strict network environment. Only one http proxy IP can be used for visiting outside.

I plan to develop a MSN bot, now, barreled by that proxy. Any suggestion? Have try on msnp and papyon, dos't work.